# Unity2D OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Hello I'm creating a 2d game and have implemented a dialogue script - When one gameObject collides with another and a specific Key on the keyboard is pressed a text box appears.

The dialogue (text boxes) appears using OnGUI with an array method behind it. This works successfully. Once the dialogue has finished the array resets, However I would then think by everything already being true i.e. the collision and with the key pressed on the keyboard that the dialogue would appear again.. it doesn't.

The only way for me to allow the dialogue to reappear again is if my gameObject moves away from the other gameObject's collider and then collides again with it. Is there anyway for me to not have to move away from the collider and then have to reinitiate contact with a collision for my dialogue to show? I don't understand why I have to if all arguments are true?

Sorry if I've described my problem poorly, I hope somebody can help.. it's possible that this is the only way OnCollision2d works.. I don't know.

Here is my code I'm using C# (I'm not sure a specific part would be substantial enough, so I'll post it all) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class showtext : MonoBehaviour 
{
bool CollisionWithHouse = false;
bool ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision = false; 

public string[] dialogue = {"Greetings?",
             "Farewell, my friend."};


int index = 0;


Rect dialogueRect = new Rect(435,100,500,50);
Rect dialogueRect2 = new Rect(335,50,300,34);

void Update() {
    if (CollisionWithHouse && (ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision && Input.GetKeyDown("r"))) 
    {
        index++;
    }

    if (CollisionWithHouse && Input.GetKeyDown("r")){

        ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision = true;    
    }

}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D house){
     {
        CollisionWithHouse = true;
    }
}



void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D house){
    CollisionWithHouse = false;
    ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision = false;
}


void OnGUI() {
    if (index < 1 && (CollisionWithHouse) && (ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision)) {
        GUI.Box(dialogueRect, dialogue[index]);
    } 
    if (index > 0 && (CollisionWithHouse) && (ActionButtonTextAppearsWithCollision)) {
        GUI.Box (dialogueRect2, dialogue [index]);
    }


    else  {
                  System.Array.Clear(dialogue,0, index = 0);
    }


    }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnCollisionEnter only fires once when the collision occurs. If you want it to fire constantly while the objects are touching, you need to use a different check, like [OnCollisionStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html).

**FROM COMMENTS**

The value `index` will never be reset while the two objects are touching. Check for the value of index you want (when the last item of `dialogue` is used) and when that's matched, reset it to 0. That way, the dialogue can be restarted right away.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that, but I still have to move the object away from colliding before I can reinitiate the dialogue again :(

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's happening? I'm a little confused on the chain of events.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have two GameObjects in my scene (a man who the player controls and NPC(named collisionwithhouse in script)). When they collide and I press the 'r' key a dialogue box will appear. The player keeps pressing the key 'r' to run through the dialogue. Once the dialogue finishes (the array) it resets. If the player want's the dialogue to appear again, I want them to just press r key, however for some reason they have to leave the NPC's collider box, and reenter (and then press the r key) for the dialogue to appear again with the newly reset array.

Comment: Are you positive that the array is being cleared correctly? It looks like `System.Array.Clear(dialogue,0, index = 0);` takes the array as the second argument and the length as the third. What happens if you change it to `System.Array.Clear(dialogue,0, 1);`?

Comment: When using the System.Array.Clear(dialogue,0, 1); the array doesn't seem to reset, I can only run through the dialogue once. If I was much better at coding I could more eloquently elaborate on what I wish to achieve, sorry. :( I appreciate the help, thanks a lot.

Comment: and it did reset before? have you walked through it with a debugger?

Comment: Okay doing some debugging I've found that using the System.Array.Clear(dialogue,0, index = 0); line the array does in fact reset, however it only resets when the two objects aren't colliding which is why I can't achieve what I want to. I need the array to reset after it has reached the dialogues end regardless of if there's a collision or not. How to achieve this..? I have no idea XD

Comment: oh, since `index` in `OnGUI()` is what is controlling what's displayed, figure out what value `index` is when the last part `dialogue` is displayed and, in `OnGUI()`, check for that and reset it when occurs.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm unsure on how to check what value the index is on. I've tried "if (index = 1)...."  but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's because `=` sets index to the value of one. Double equals `==` is an equality check.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that's exactly what I needed. I decided to just use '==' instead of  '>' or '<' than throughout. Works perfectly now. Appreciate you taking the time to stick it out with my inexperience :D I'll mark your main post as correct.. or is that not how it works?

Comment: It is, I'll add some of my comments to my answer to make it more complete. Glad I could help :) good luck